# Netbeans and Git

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I am very new to git/versioning

I create a git repository with netbeans, commit the project and when i try to "upload" (?) it (using command line):

```
git remote add origin git@github:my_username/my_project_name.git
git push -u origin master
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Алексей Резников\My Projects\netbeans\CourseProject2011>git push -u origin master
Could not create directory '/c/Users/\200\253\245\252\341\245\251 \220\245\247\255\250\252\256\242/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is to:p0:se:cr:et:0f:in:ge:rp:ri:nt:0k:ey:00:00:00.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/Users/\200\253\245\252\341\245\251 \220\245\247\255\250\252\256\242/.ssh/known_hosts).
Connection closed by 207.97.227.239
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Maybe you can tell me, how to do it correctly? Thank you

windows 7, netbenas 7.0.1, git 1.7.6

Comment: Have you gone through the `git init` and setup steps (or did NetBeans do this for you)? http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/ I tend to rely on the github.com documentation, and do everything by hand at the command line. You don't really need NetBeans to manage this for you, and if this is your first repository, learning ot do it by hand can be very beneficial.

Comment: yes, i have gone through the `git init` by myself. Just went through all the steps by hand - same problem :(

Comment: I also confused. 
How to upload my current Netbeans project into the GitHub repo? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *looks* like your ssh client might be confused by the Cyrillic characters in your home directory name:

```
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/Users/\200\253\245\252\341\245\251 \220\245\247\255\250\252\256\242/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

Your ssh client will try to write an entry to the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and the above error reports an error doing that (unfortunately, it doesn't say what the error is). For diagnostics, try changing `HOME` to point somewhere else without Cyrillic characters to see what happens:

```
mkdir /c/test_home
export HOME=/c/test_home
git push -u origin master
```

If that works, then it's probably related to your user name. If that also fails, then the problem may lie somewhere else.